# Simple PHP caching creates too many files - Subfolders needed

Tags: php, caching, substring

I'm using a script i found on stack overflow a while ago for caching my dynamic php page and I'm quite satisfied with the simple solution since it's just working and i was able to integrate it with my rudimental knowledge :D It's only php code without the use of .htaccess

A MD5-hash of the URL is created to create a unique name for the caching file. However, now there are a lot of files (around 300.000) in my folder, its annoying to wait when opening the folder via ftp regarding the loading times. To reduce the number of files in one folder, I'm looking for a solution to use the first two letters as name of sub folders.

**How it works at the moment:**

- URL: e72b0f58601e6d0c12f71a40b14101b7
- File: cache/e72b0f58601e6d0c12f71a40b14101b7.html

**Wished solution:**

- URL: e72b0f58601e6d0c12f71a40b14101b7
- File: cache/e7/e72b0f58601e6d0c12f71a40b14101b7.html

The sub folders should be created automatically if they don't exist. Is someone able to help me with the code or are there any concerns against this solution?

Thought about using the substr-command, but my "experiments" didn't work quite well.

Thanks in advance!

Update: Thanks to the replies, i was able to edit the code successfully. The needed changes can be found under the original code

Code I'm using for caching (source: stackflow / http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/09/php-cache-dynamic-pages-speed-up-load-times/ )

```
<?php
//settings
$cache_ext  = '.html'; //file extension
$cache_time     = 3600;  //Cache file expires afere these seconds (1 hour = 3600 sec)
$cache_folder   = 'cache/'; //folder to store Cache files
$ignore_pages   = array('', '');

$dynamic_url    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // requested dynamic page (full url)
$cache_file     = $cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$cache_ext; // construct a cache file
$ignore = (in_array($dynamic_url,$ignore_pages))?true:false; //check if url is in ignore list

if (!$ignore && file_exists($cache_file) && time() - $cache_time < filemtime($cache_file)) { //check Cache exist and it's not expired.
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); //Turn on output buffering, "ob_gzhandler" for the compressed page with gzip.
    readfile($cache_file); //read Cache file
    echo '<!-- cached page - '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', filemtime($cache_file)).', Page : '.$dynamic_url.' -->';
    ob_end_flush(); //Flush and turn off output buffering
    exit(); //no need to proceed further, exit the flow.
}
//Turn on output buffering with gzip compression.
ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); 
######## Your Website Content Starts Below #########
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page to Cache</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ut tellus libero.
        </body>
</html>
<?php
######## Your Website Content Ends here #########

if (!is_dir($cache_folder)) { //create a new folder if we need to
    mkdir($cache_folder);
}
if(!$ignore){
    $fp = fopen($cache_file, 'w');  //open file for writing
    fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); //write contents of the output buffer in Cache file
    fclose($fp); //Close file pointer
}
ob_end_flush(); //Flush and turn off output buffering

?>
```

If you're interested in the solution, these lines need to be updated:

Original:

```
 $cache_folder   = 'cache/'; //folder to store Cache files
 $dynamic_url    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // requested dynamic page (full url)
```

Updated (Dynamic Url is the same, but is mentioned here due to a different order):

```
$dynamic_url    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // requested dynamic page (full url)
$cache_folder   = 'cache/'.substr(md5($dynamic_url),0,2).'/'; //folder to store Cache files
```

...

Original:

```
if (!is_dir($cache_folder)) { //create a new folder if we need to
mkdir($cache_folder);
}
```

Updated:

```
if (!is_dir($cache_folder)) { //create a new folder if we need to
mkdir($cache_folder, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: Splitting the md5 hash and generating the right directories and file-paths seems pretty straight-forward. What have you tried so far and how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$cache_file = $cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$cache_ext; // construct a cache file
...
if (!is_dir($cache_folder)) { //create a new folder recuirsively if we need to
    mkdir($cache_folder);
}
```

Use

```
$cache_folder .= substr(md5($dynamic_url),0,2) . '/';
$cache_file = $cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$cache_ext;
...
if (!is_dir($cache_folder)) { //create a new folder if we need to
        mkdir($cache_folder, 0777, true);
}
```

This will add the first to characters of the filename as a new subfolder and create that folder recursively if it does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, but regarding the folder it only checks and creates the main folders and not the subfolders, or?

Comment: Just some minor changes, but with your approach it's working. Thanks a lot! :)

I'm going to update my question with your solution

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer did help you solve your problem then consider marking the answer as "solution" or upvoting the answer.

Comment: Okay i did! Maybe you should edit your answer a last time, have a look at my updated $cache_folder, which considers a main folder ! I tried to upvote, but my reputation here is still too low.

Answer (score 0):

> its annoying to wait when opening the folder via ftp regarding the loading times

I am not aware of an "opening the folder" operation in FTP. Certainly if you are getting a listing of the folder, it will take time to transfer the data, and to render at your client. It does beg the question of what you gain by looking in the folder.

What may be more of an issue is the time it takes to locate an individual item in the cache and to identify candidates for eviction - but that is completely dependent on the filesystem the data resides in - and you've provided no details of that nor the timings for these processes.

300,000 is a lot of files - it might be the right number - again you've not provided any indication as to whether this is expected. OTOH it might point to an issue with the method of generate cache keys and whether it is appropriate for your application.

To use sub folders, simply change:

```
$cache_file = $cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$cache_ext;
```

to

```
$cache_file = $cache_folder.mk_hash_path($dynamic_url,$cache_folder).$cache_ext;
...

function mk_hash_path($dynamic_url,$cache_folder)
{
  md5($dynamic_url);
  $subfolders=4;
  while ($subfolders--) {
     $hash=substr($hash, -$subfolders, 1) . '/' . $hash;
  }
  if (!is_dir(dirname($cache_folder . $hash))) {
      mkdir(dirname($cache_folder . $hash,0777, true))
  }
  return $hash;
}
```

But a much netter idea would be to use a caching reverse proxy.

Comment: Thank you, too! In my case the number of files is proper / intended ;) The script is using a lot of APIs, so it was the simplest solution to reduce loading speed and the number of requests to the API-Servers. However, i agree that i should using another solution in the future (memcache, varnish etc.) - but atm i have to stay on a file-based cache =)

Am i right that i have to copy the function (mk_hash_path) above the variable-declaration of cache_file since in order to run properly or doesn't it matter?

Comment: You need the function as well as the change to the name generation.

Comment: No, i'm sorry - not a native speaker, i meant the chronological order of your code, since the first line of your code is referring to the function which comes later in your code. I tried to implement it, but it failed in this way. However, i was successful with max' approach :) thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

Consider using other caching mechanism rather than file cache.

You should use redis or memcache as your cache store. For full page cache opt for CDN solution. There are free CDN available like cloudfront.

Comment: This is not really an answer, more a comment.

Comment: Yeah, i will using another technique at some point in the future, but at the moment it's not possible :()